# Does spring-cloud-stream Horsham support Spring Boot 2.3?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

So on [Spring Cloud Streams : Overview](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#overview) they have the following then the version is labelled as `Horsham.SR8 [3.0.8 RELEASE]`:

[image: table of release trains for spring cloud stream]

But then [this comment says `Hoxton.SR5`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1971#issuecomment-633675415)

However, currently in my application where I'm attempting to upgrade from Spring `2.1.X` and Spring Cloud `Greenwich` to Spring `2.3.3` and Spring Cloud ? (currently `Hoston.SR8`) I get the following:

```
2020-08-31 15:16:59.561 WARN  [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -  - Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@512ddf17]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1737)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1614)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1243)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:880)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:868)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:855)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:806)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.myapplicaiton.MyApplicationKt.main(MyApplicationKt.kt:78)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/function/context/PollableBean
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.function.context.PollableBean
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of spring-cloud-function-context do you have on the classpath?

I created a new Boot 2.3.3/Hoxton.SR8 app this morning and I see that class in `spring-cloud-function-context-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar` which should automatically be picked up.

Comment: Thanks Gary this was the cause of that issue had explicitly been defaulting it to the old `2.1.1`